# Conditional back navigation with Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

Im making navigation in my app using navigation component from jetpack.
I have 3 screens in my app, all of them implemented via Fragment:
 - search screen 
 - list screen 
 - detail screen

When user presses search (on `search screen`), app navigates to `list screen` loads results and displays them. User selects one of the results and navigates to `detail screen`. If there is only one result, app navigates from `list screen` to `detail screen` automatically, effectively skipping list screen.

The problem is back navigation: when there was multiple results I need to navigate back to `list screen`, but if there was only one result I need to navigate back to `search screen`. I want just call `navigateUp`, but this will take me to `list screen` (in all cases) and then forward to `detail screen` if there is only one result.

When using `FragmentTransaction` directly, we can `replace` current fragment with and call `addToBackStack` only if we want to return to it later.
When using navigation component we can just `navigate`, and it behaves as `replace` + `addToBackStack`.

How can I achieve replace-without-adding-to-backstack behavior using architecture component?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @JohnSardinha Yeap, its below!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I managed how to achieve it.
Now I have two actions with the same start and destination, their only difference is `popUpTo` attribute.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_detailFragement"
    app:destination="@id/detailFragment"/>

<action
    android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_detailFragement_pop"
    app:destination="@id/detailFragment"
    app:popUpTo="@id/listFragment"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

`action_listFragment_to_detailFragement` is used when user manually performes transition and it should return to list screen later

`action_listFragment_to_detailFragement_pop` is used when transition performed automatically and list screen should not be shown after return.

Answer (score 0):

In Navigation Component, you can use the method `NavController.popBackStack(int action)` which works similar to `addToBackStack(null)`.

Comment: I just have this method in NavController
`public boolean popBackStack(@IdRes int destinationId, boolean inclusive)`
and, by the way, I want opposite: skip adding to a backstack

Answer (score 0):

### Just use { Safe-Args Directions } instead of ID:

---

```
override fun navigateTo(navController: NavController) {
    val action = 
        FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment()
    navController.navigate(action)
}
```

---