# Navigation Components conditional popUpTo?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

Newbie on Navigation Component. I'm trying to achieve this but I don't know how:

I have 3 fragments:

`FragmentMain` → `FragmentList` → `FragmentAdd`

If I try to go from `FragmentMain` to `FragmentList` but list is empty it should go directly to `FragmentAdd` (its not really directly since I'm checking the list on FragmentList but for the user it should look like it). If I'm on `FragmentAdd` and I go back (by either pressing back button or back on the toolbar) it should go back to `FragmentMain` (since `FragmentList` is still empty) but if I add something it should go back to `FragmentList`.

I've tried with

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain" >
    <action android:id="@+id/action_fragmentMain_to_fragmentList
        app:destination="@id/fragmentList"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentMain"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```

The thing is that if I press back on `FragmentAdd` it will go to `FragmentList`, check that the list is still empty and go back to `FragmentAdd`. And if I pop `FragmentList` and then add something It will go to `FragmentMain` and not the list.

The difference with [Conditional back navigation with Android Navigation Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541987/conditional-back-navigation-with-android-navigation-component) is that I can add stuff to `FragmentList` from `FragmentAdd`

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `app:popUpTo="@id/FragmentList" and app:popUpToInclusive="true"` in action action_fragmentList_to_fragmentAdd

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMain" >
    <action android:id="@+id/action_fragmentMain_to_fragmentList
        app:destination="@id/fragmentList"/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentList" >
    <action android:id="@+id/action_fragmentList_to_fragmentAdd
        app:destination="@id/fragmentAdd"
        app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentList"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentAdd" >
</fragment>
```